# Calling Main Program Method from DLL

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I have a main program which is dynamically loading DLL Files and activating one class file which contains all core operations, presuming that the class inherits and the Plugin interface.

I have two methods on the main form which I am passing via the Plugin Interface as Action, I assign the methods to the Action within the plugin during the Assembly loading period, I then call those Actions and pass a value which executes the method from the main program and performs its task.

What I am wondering here is if there is any other alternative to doing this other than using Action/Func delegates, without referencing the main program (Both must stay separate, related ONLY by the IPlugin interface which is another DLL referenced in the main program & plugin projects) and without using any Method Invoking within the plugin DLL file itself.

Or is it a case where I am already using the best method suitable?

--Edit--

```
//Interface
interface IPlugin
{
    Action<string> myAction;
}

//Main Program
public class MainForm
{
    void LoadPlugins(Action<string> myMethod) 
    {
        List<Assembly> Assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.dll")) { Assemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(file)); }
        foreach (Assembly a in Assemblies)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(a.GetName());
            foreach (Type x in a.GetTypes())
            {
                if (x.IsInterface || x.IsAbstract || x.GetInterface(typeof(IPlugin).FullName) == null) { continue; }
                IPlugin plugin = (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(x);
                plugin.myAction = myMethod;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnLoad()
    {
        LoadPlugins(UpdateGUI);
    }

    void UpdateGUI(string Message)
    {
        txtBlockReport.Text += Message;
    }
}

//Plugin compiled as DLL, implementing & referencing IPlugin Interface.
public class MyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public Action<string> myAction { get; set; }

    void OnLoad()
    {
        myAction("Plugin Loaded");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have the main form (or some other object) implement another interface which exposes these two methods, and pass it to the plugin that way.

Comment: The main program has a class which implements the Plugin interface and I call the interface in the main forms logic for buttons.

Example: Main form generates controls and sets a Buttons Click EH to execute (Button.Tag as IPlugin).Method("Argument"); - I was going to create methods in the Interface and use the same method, but the problem is that logically I am thinking of it executing a method in the DLL file, when I want the DLL file to execute a method in the main program.

Comment: @ColinMurphy too much puzzling descriptive information. How about you try posting some code? [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be awesome

Comment: I've updated my main post with example code of what I'm currently doing, and looking to do. Action<T> works, but I'm also wondering if any other alternative works while keeping the two programs separate.

Comment: And what are you trying to replace / avoid?

Comment: I am avoiding nothing particularly, just wondering if this is the best way of doing this and if there would be any performance changes in any other way

Comment: The alternative way can be to use event instead of action method. In IPlugin interface declare an event and then subscribe to that event when loading plugin. It doesn't make much difference to what you are already doing, but I think using event instead of Action method is more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed some of the discretionary Actions from the Interface and instead have created a custom event handler statically, within a class (In the Plugin Interface DLL File), to receive updates on both Program & Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a "Host" interface, have the methods there, and pass that into the Plugin.

Alternatively, you could use a shared source file that only contains a delegate signature (so no reference and no dependency), which is basically what you're doing when using `Func`, only you can make it more precise and better named.

Comment: How would the Host interface look in that case?. I have also just replied to my original post with how I was going to do it before I realized that it would be the main program calling the method on the DLL.